# How often does an SSAE 16 audit have to be performed in order to be good enough for HIPPA compliance

Tags: security

I need to find a dedicated hosting service that has (among other things) passed SSAE 16 audit. I found one that had the audit performed between 1/1/2013 and 6/1/2013. Should that be considered current enough? I'm not sure how often that audit must be performed to be considered current. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should expect a service to have an SSAE 16 audit [annually](http://www.ssae16.org/important-elements-ssae16/ssae-16-audit-frequency.html). While [this isn't a strict requirement](http://www.ssae16.org/important-elements-ssae16/ssae-16-type-ii-compliant.html) of the standard, regulatory requirements change, new technology is added to the environment, etc. An out of date report may not be useful.

> While we will stop short of calling it an annual "requirement", customers and other intended users of SSAE 16 Type II reports will come to expect - and demand - such reporting on an annual basis. The "one and done" approach unfortunately does not work in today's world of growing regulatory compliance mandates.